# How to make Logcat remain full screen in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Question, every time I open Android Studio my Logcat changes back to a small approximately `480x480` pixel window. I then resize it to full screen by dragging the corner but this soon goes back to the standard above mentioned dimensions.

There is also no maximise button, only a close.

I've looked around and nobody seems to have a solution. Has anyone been able to work around this?

Additional info: `Windows 8.1.`

Answer (score 1):

There is an option to maximize logcat window, see below screenshot,

[image]

Also, you can maximize or minimize using keyboard short cuts,

> cntrl+shift+up arrow

to maximize by streching it upwards

> cntrl+shift+down arrow

to minimize by streching it downwards

Just make sure you select `Android Monitor` by clicking it once.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I have tried this however this only works if the window is docked, I have it floating as I need it on my other monitor which is side by side to the main one.

Comment: I updated my answer please have a look if that helps.

Comment: That still only works if I have it displayed on the same monitor.